# Calculate value from an existent column based on condition with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with the columns "gender" and "economy" with the following observations:

```
  gender  economy
1    Male      Bad
2  Female      Bad
3  Female      Bad
4    Male      Bad
5    Male     Good
6    Male      Bad
7    Male Very bad
8    Male Very bad
9    Male Very bad
10   Male Very bad
11 Female      Bad
12   Male     Good
13   Male     Good
14 Female     Good
15   Male      Bad
16 Female     Good
17 Female Very bad
18   Male Very bad
19 Female     Good
20 Female      Bad

structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), economy = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Very good", "Good", "Bad", "Very bad", "Don't know"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate now the shares of females and males with the summed value of respondents saying that economy is either bad or very bad. I could just calculcate it manually outside of R, but I want to know a quick way to calculate it within R. I do know how to calculate shares, but now I'm stuck:

```
lebanon %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(economy), economy != "Don't know") %>%
  count(economy) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n) * 100)

  gender economy       n   prop
  <fct>  <fct>     <int>  <dbl>
1 Female Very good     7  0.586
2 Female Good        146 12.2  
3 Female Bad         544 45.6  
4 Female Very bad    497 41.6  
5 Male   Very good     5  0.417
6 Male   Good        161 13.4  
7 Male   Bad         515 42.9  
8 Male   Very bad    519 43.2
```

Greetings

Comment: The percentage of respondents thinking the economy is bad or very bad would be given by `100 * length(grep("B|bad", lebanon$economy))/nrow(lebanon)`

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is there another way where I could get the result for each gender like in the table I posted here? So I have four rows, two for each gender, with summed values "very good/good" and "very bad/bad". That would make it easier to use it with ggplot.

Comment: Hi Nicosc - yes. I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with your initial `lebanon` data frame (which I was able to recover from your summary table using `uncount`), and try this code, which uses `forcats::fct_collapse` to combine the desired factor levels.

I've included a simple ggplot at the end for completeness.

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- lebanon %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  filter(!is.na(economy), economy != "Don't know") %>%
  mutate(economy = fct_collapse(economy,
                   `Bad or very bad` = c("Bad", "Very bad"),
                   `Good or very good` = c("Good", "Very good"))
         ) %>%
  count(economy) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n) * 100)
           
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   gender [2]
#>   gender economy               n  prop
#>   <fct>  <fct>             <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Female Bad or very bad    1041  87.2
#> 2 Female Good or very good   153  12.8
#> 3 Male   Bad or very bad    1034  86.2
#> 4 Male   Good or very good   166  13.8

ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = prop, fill = economy)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red3", "forestgreen")) +
  labs(title = "Opinion on economy by gender", y = "Percentage of those polled")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might help :

```
library(dplyr)

lebanon %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(grepl('Good', economy, ignore.case = TRUE), 'Good', 'Bad')) %>%
  count(gender, type)

#  gender type n
#1 Female  Bad 5
#2 Female Good 3
#3   Male  Bad 9
#4   Male Good 3
```

This turns `"Good/Very Good"` in one type and `"Bad/Very Bad"` in another.